# N-step code for fibonacci OCAML

Tags: algorithm, ocaml, fibonacci

So I'm trying to code something for my class that will output an int list of the first k terms in an n-step fibonacci sequence.

So for those of you that don't know, an n step fibonacci sequence is when you add the n numbers before it to get the next one,

```
so for n=1 it'd be 1,1,1,1,1,...
n=2, it'd be 1,1,2,3,5,...
n=3 it'd be 1,1,2,4,7...
```

My approach was to start of with a base case, so

```
let rec n_step n k= 

if k=1 then [1] else 

if n=1 then 1::nacci n k-1 else
```

but now I'm stuck here. I know I need to iterate through and add up the terms in the list, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

I made a helper function sum

```
let rec sum lst =
  match lst with
  | [] ->  0
  | h::t -> h + sum t
```

I was trying to make it selectively add the last n numbers of the list to get the next value but I got stuck on that as well

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried, to get that iteration done? Where are you storing your data? How are you picking which data to aggregate from that data structure?

Comment: I coded a helper function sum which would sum up the values in a given list (I'll add that up there) but I was sure how to make this selectively add up the last n numbers for the next value

Comment: I think you need to show a bit more code, is the thing.  I assume you have a multi-valued data structure of some sort, so that you can do some addition of N number of elements?  And that you're not going to let it grow forever, so you're either using a queue-like structure (LIFO) or are manipulating a fixed array and doing it yourself?

Comment: As this is homework, I'm kinda feeling like you should be working for it ... but my general approach here would probably to 1) build an array, 2) seed it with 0's, 3) drop in a number, 4) sum all numbers, 5) shift the array, 6) put in your summed up number from step 4, 7) loop.

Comment: I'll work on it some more and show you what I come up with, but I'm not really sure about LIFO, the prompt was really short.

Comment: Agreed, probably not best use case for queue - too much complexity when you could manage it in a simpler data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out using many helper functions.

So I've made a sum function that would sum up the values in a list
A gather function that would only take the n values from the entire list

and then in my original function, I used pattern matching for the k's such that if k=1, it would yield one and otherwise it would recurse. If it wasn't one I appended the next value using the helper

Answer (score 1):

This is homework so I'll only suggest some steps, not a complete solution:

- if you come from an imperative background, try first an imperative solution such as a loop that prints the result instead of building a list and tying the recursion at once. You can store the required state in a global and gradually change that to pass parameters.
- start with n=2, using a tuple instead of a list. It will be considerably easier to do that first, manually extend to fixed n=3 and fixed n=4 before using a list.

Applying these two pieces of advice, a first step might be:

```
let print_fib_2 () =
  let previous_ref = ref (1, 1) in
  for i = 0 to 10 do
    let (a, b) = !previous_ref in
    let next = a + b in
    previous_ref := (next, a);
    Printf.printf "%d\n" next
  done
```

I'd first generalize to using changing `n=2` to `n=3`: what happens to the pairs `(a, b)` and `(next, a)`? what does it mean in terms of lists?

By following baby steps from a working example you should be able to work to a solution.